# True heading and true course of an iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, compass, heading

I am working on some project where I required to make an app which can tell course of an iphone but without GPS. I can use GPS to get initial fix.

Now I can get true heading using compass but that is the orientation of phone w.r.t north pole not the direction in which phone is moving?

How can I get course using compass.

I have looked at accelerometer also but in most of the stack quesions it is advised not to use acclerometer for distance and speed calculation.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: The compass provides magnetic heading, not true heading.

Comment: Yes I know that but in iphone you can get true heading also

Answer (score 0):

The 'course' you are referring to is actually the ground speed vector measured by the GPS (measured by combining two or more consecutive GPS readings and calculating the speed using the timestamps : v = dx/dt).

The compass has nothing to do with course. You can hold your iPhone however you want and walk at a certain direction. Your compass is sensitive to your phone orientation, not movement.

The accelerometer, as its name implies, measures acceleration. It would be difficult to deduce your course solely from that information because of noise.

So your solution is found in CLLocation class : properties speed and course
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed

Comment: Yes if I dont want to use GPS then how can we get the speed?

Comment: You can use location services, which uses other sources than GPS, like cell towers and Wifi access points. These work indoors, where GPS doesn't.